# Doing a push and update of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am attempting to do is get unique values stored in the array and if a element gets pushed to the JSON string with the same MAC and IP I would like to make it replace the existing record with the new one it could replace it all or just the signal, distance and frequency I don't have a solid piece of code I am currently just experimenting trying to get what I need. Bellow is an example of the json output from my javascript console in chrome I know it's not formatted the best but it is valid.

```
{"prey":["{\"distance\": 8.686924173343307, \"signal\": \"-59\", \"frequency\": 2447, \"mac\": \"00:00:00:00:00:00\", \"ip\": \"192.168.43.27\"}"]}
```

What I have tried do far is use a for loop to check for duplicates this did not work as javascript was returning the wrong length of the array for some reason and it just got stuck in a infinite loop because I kept adding values to the array and it wasn't working in the unique way it should.

This is the code I currently have as I just keep hacking away at it trying everything I can think of this does not work in any way I have been playing with trying to get unique array but it just doesn't work the output of this is just the same as the actual output it does not get the unique array. I got the unique function from a stack overflow question

```
function arrayLastUnique(array) {
    return array.filter(function (a, b, c) {
        // keeps last occurrence
        return c.indexOf(a, b + 1) < 0;
    });
}

jsonSpy['prey'].push(msg);
$('#lines').append($('<p>').text(msg)); 
console.log(arrayLastUnique(jsonSpy.prey));
spyList = JSON.stringify(jsonSpy);
drawPositions(ctx, spyList);
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. It should be like `{"prey":[{}]}` instead of `{"prey":["{}"]}`

Comment: Yeah I mucked up pasting it in removed the bit I shouldn't have I'l fix it now

Comment: It is copied from my google chrome debug console

Comment: Can you elaborate _if the mac and ip combination exists and if it does update the other bits of data_?

Comment: The json is correct check it on jsonlint.com

Comment: It is json or I wouldn't have asked the question like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yourJSON = {"prey":
    [
        { "distance": 8.686924173343307,   
          "signal": "-59",   
          "frequency": 2447,   
          "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",   
          "ip": "192.168.43.27"
        }
    ]
};

var newDistance = 8.69;

if (yourJSON["prey"][0]["mac"] && yourJSON["prey"][0]["ip"]) {
    yourJSON["prey"][0]["distance"] = newDistance;
}
```

If the values for "mac" and "ip" exist i.e. they are not an empty string, `false`, 0, `null`, `undefined`, the condition is satisfied. In the condition block you can assign a new value. This is just a very simple example. You have to adapt it and expand it according to your needs.